# Cartesian Join on Country and Swimmer tables, but exclude labeled Countries

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a cartesian join on 2 tables where the columns in one table serve as flags that exclude certain swimmers from the list:

```
Table 1: Country List
Code    Name
--------------------------------
FR      France
NE      Netherlands
BE      Belgium
```

Here's the Second table:

```
Table 2: Swimmer List
SwimmerName      FR    NE    BE
--------------------------------
Swimmer1                N
Swimmer2          N
Swimmer3
```

Basically I need to make a cartesian join, but exclude the records where the country is marked as N.

Expected result:

```
Swimmer1   FR
Swimmer1   BE
Swimmer2   NE
Swimmer2   BE
Swimmer3   FR
Swimmer3   NE
Swimmer3   BE
```

Notice that if the country has been flagged as N, it's not included in the result. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: what `RDBMS` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the country abbreviations are column names in your second table. One way to do this doesn't use the first table... you could use something like:

```
select SwimmerName, "FR" from SwimmerList where FR<>"N"
union
select SwimmerName, "NE" from SwimmerList where NE<>"N"
union
select SwimmerName, "BE" from SwimmerList where BE<>"N"
```

Comment: Good point! I never considered that I actually don't need the first table. :) This worked for me in achieving my goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way of doing is to unpivot the country columns in your SwimmerList using UNPIVOT [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Here is the example code:

```
-- set up sample data
DECLARE @SwimmerList TABLE (SwimmerName NVARCHAR(10), FR CHAR, NE CHAR, BE CHAR)
INSERT @SwimmerList(SwimmerName,FR,NE,BE)
VALUES ('Swimmer1', '', 'N', ''),
    ('Swimmer2', 'N', '', ''),
    ('Swimmer3', '', '', '')

-- unpivot
SELECT
    SwimmerName, CountryCode
FROM
    (SELECT SwimmerName, FR, NE, BE
    FROM @SwimmerList) AS sl
UNPIVOT
    (CountryExists FOR CountryCode IN (FR, NE, BE)) AS unpvt
WHERE CountryExists <> 'N'
```

SQLFiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bebb27/1/0)

Note: This solution works for SQL Server 2005 or later.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about UNPIVOT.